# How can I remove absolute paths of html files in sourcemap for aurelia-cli project?

Tags: source-maps, aurelia

I am new to Aurelia and working on a project using aurelia-cli.  I noticed that the generated sourcemap includes absolute path names for my html template files.  I prefer that the sourcemap did not include absolute path names.  Alternatively, and maybe preferably, I would like the html file names left out of the sourcemap altogether since html files are not very useful in the sourcemap.  How can I get aurelia-cli to put relative file names in the sourcemap or to remove references to html files altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the CLI. It has been fixed, but the fix has not been released. It should be released today.

Here is the commit that fixed the bug: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/commit/127a8abc15e23fcbe2ceee42582baafbea5acb74

Comment: I upgraded to aurelia-cli version 0.23.0 (from 0.22.0) and the html template files no longer appear in the sourcemap.  Thanks!